# Decorators must precede the name and all keywords of property declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, decorator

I created a decorator called @Inject in typescript file, like this

```js
export class A{
    @Inject()
    private b!: string

    @Inject()
    private c!: string
}
```

But vscode told me there was a mistake

```js
export class A{
    @Inject()
    private b!: string

    @Inject() //error : Decorators must precede the name and all keywords of property declarations.
    private c!: string
}
```

But when I execute the TSC command, the terminal does not display any errors.

The strangest thing is that when I end with a semicolon, the error disappears.

```js
export class A{
    @Inject()
    private b!: string ;

    @Inject()
    private c!: string ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must to change version typescript in visual studio code. for me version typescript is 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to search after your Typescript version and change it to your current workspace version instead of the vscode typescript version which is currently a dev verison.

First search after `>Typescript: Version`

[image]

Than you can selest the current workspace verison

[image]

You also can click on the bottom right corner on the typscript version and change it to your current workspace version.